# How to split a PHP loop in 2 parts?

Tags: php

I have a weather json from where I get a wether forecast for 8 days. My problem is that I want to show the result in a table of 2 rows of 4 days each. 
I managed to do it but in a very odd way that was pure begginer's luck during a trial-error-trial attempt :-) I don't even understand quite well why it is splitting the result in 2 rows... but it works!!! The only thing I could not do was to include a "hr" line between the 2 rows, to make the table easier to read. 
You can see the result here http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao_ds.php 
With current code I am displaying each day forecasted values inside the same "td" in different lines using "br". I have been reading that it is not correct to use "br" inside "td" so I am not sure that I am doing the righ thing. 
Wouldn't it be better to use a table with 4 columns (one for each day) and have different rows for each of the values? 
Is there any way to rewrite this code to make it more efficient and look less "childish"? :-) Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
     (...)
 $decoded = json_decode($rawData, true); 
?>
 <table>
<?php for($k=0;$k<8;$k++){ 
$dailyvalue = $decoded['daily']['data'][$k];

    $dailyTime = $dailyvalue['time'];
$dailyIcon = $dailyvalue['icon'];
$dailyTempMax = round($dailyvalue['temperatureMax'],0); 
$dailyTempMin = round($dailyvalue['temperatureMin'],0);
      (...)
 ?> 

  <!-- table for 8 day's forecast (2 rows/4 days each) -->
<td>
<?php echo strftime("%a %d",$dailyTime) ?>
 <br>
<?php echo '<img src="path/'.$dailyIcon.'.png">' ?>
 <br>
<?php echo $dailyTempMin.'º' ?> </span>
 <br>
 <?php echo $dailyTempMax.'º' ?></span>
  <br>
        (...)   

 <?php if ($k == 3) {
    echo '</td></tr>';    
  } ?>

 <?php
}
 ?>
</td></tr><table>
```

Comment: I recommend that, instead of putting the table output inside the loop, that you first loop from 0 to 7 and populate four arrays worth of data ($dailyTime, $dailyIcon, $dailyTempMax, $dailyTempMin).  After that, you can then run two different loops ($k from 0 to 3, and $k from 4 to 7), where you output your data in whatever order you wish.  Anything you want "between" those two tables can be put between the loops.

Comment: @TheMouseMaster Thank you so much for your reply and it seems to be the perfect answer for my question. I have been working on it, but always end up with the error screen :-) That's the price I pay for beeing a beginer. I can easily work on a written code by trial-error but creating a code from scratch is very difficult for me. Could you please help me by creating a short exemple of the inicial code to loop from 0 to 7 and populate four arrays worth of data, as you mentioned? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment-request, here's some sample-pseudo code, based on your code above:

```
<?php
    (...)
$decoded = json_decode($rawData, true); 
for($k=0;$k<8;$k++){ 
    $dailyvalue = $decoded['daily']['data'][$k];

    $dailyTime[$k] = $dailyvalue['time'];
    $dailyIcon[$k] = $dailyvalue['icon'];
    $dailyTempMax[$k] = round($dailyvalue['temperatureMax'],0); 
    $dailyTempMin[$k] = round($dailyvalue['temperatureMin'],0);
}

?>
<table>
<?php
echo "<tr>";
for($k = 0; $k <= 3; $k++){
    echo "<td>".strftime("%a %d",$dailyTime[$k])."</td>"; // this will make the "datetime" row
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
for($k = 0; $k <= 3; $k++){
    echo "<td><img src=path/".$dailyIcon[$k].".png></td>"; // this will make the "icon" row
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
for($k = 0; $k <= 3; $k++){
    echo "<td>".$dailyTempMin[$k]."º</td>"; // this will make the "MinTemp" row
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
for($k = 0; $k <= 3; $k++){
    echo "<td>".$dailyTempMax[$k]."º</td>"; // this will make the "MaxTemp" row
}
echo "</tr>";
// put stuff you want between the tables here
echo "<tr>";
for($k = 4; $k <= 7; $k++){
     // proceed to do the same as above
```

Mind you, there are further ways you can reduce the screen clutter (like moving the table-drawing for loops into a function), but this is the general gist of it

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This is exactly what I was looking for, and your help was fantastic! You can't  imagine how happy I am now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply stack two different table on each other ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I am going to try that :-)